# Using JodaTime in Spark's groupByKey and countByKey

Tags: jodatime, apache-spark

I have a very simple Spark program (using Flambo in Clojure, but should be easy to follow). These are all objects on the JVM. I'm testing on a `local` instance (although I would guess that Spark still serialises and deserialises).

```
(let [dt (t/date-time 2014)
      input (f/parallelize sc [{:the-date dt :x "A"}
                               {:the-date dt :x "B"}
                               {:the-date dt :x "C"}
                               {:the-date dt :x "D"}])
      by-date (f/map input (f/fn [{the-date :the-date x :x}] [the-date x])))
```

Input is an RDD of four tuples, each with the same date object. The first map produces a key-value RDD of date => x.

The content of `input` is, as expected:

```
=> (f/foreach input prn)
[#<DateTime 2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z> "A"]
[#<DateTime 2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z> "B"]
[#<DateTime 2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z> "C"]
[#<DateTime 2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z> "D"]
```

Just to be clear, equality and `.hashCode` work on the date object :

```
=> (= dt dt)
true
=> (.hashCode dt)
1260848926
=> (.hashCode dt)
1260848926
```

They are instances of JodaTime's [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html), which [implement equals as expected](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.html#equals-java.lang.Object-).

When I try `countByKey`, I get the expected:

```
=> (f/count-by-key by-date)
{#<DateTime 2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z> 4}
```

But when I `groupByKey`, it doesn't seem to work.

```
=> (f/foreach (f/group-by-key by-date) prn)
[#<DateTime 2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z> ["A"]]
[#<DateTime 2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z> ["B"]]
[#<DateTime 2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z> ["C"]]
[#<DateTime 2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z> ["D"]]
```

The keys are all identical so I would expect the result to be a single entry with the date as the key and `["A", "B", "C", "D"]` as the value. Something's happening because the values are all lists.

Somehow `groupByKey` isn't correctly equating the keys. But `countByKey` is. What's the difference between the two? How can I make them behave the same?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm getting closer toward an answer. I think this belongs in the answer section rather than the question section.

This groups by key, turns into a local collect, extracts the first item (date).

```
=> (def result-dates (map first (f/collect (f/group-by-key by-date))))
=> result-dates
(#<DateTime 2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z>
 #<DateTime 2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z>
 #<DateTime 2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z>
 #<DateTime 2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z>)
```

The hashcodes are all the same

```
=> (map #(.hashCode %) result-dates)
(1260848926
 1260848926
 1260848926 
 1260848926)
```

The milliseconds are all the same:

```
=> (map #(.getMillis %) result-dates)
(1388534400000
 1388534400000
 1388534400000
 1388534400000)
```

`equals` fails, but `isEquals` succeeds

```
=> (.isEqual (first result-dates) (second result-dates))
true

=> (.equals (first result-dates) (second result-dates))
false
```

[documentation for `.equals` says](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> Compares this object with the specified object for equality based on the millisecond instant and the Chronology

Their milliseconds are all equal and their Chronologies appear to be:

```
=> (map #(.getChronology %) result-dates)
(#<ISOChronology ISOChronology[UTC]>
 #<ISOChronology ISOChronology[UTC]>
 #<ISOChronology ISOChronology[UTC]>
 #<ISOChronology ISOChronology[UTC]>)
```

However, the Chronologies *don't* equate.

```
=> (def a (first result-dates))
=> (def b (second result-dates))

=> (= (.getChronology a) (.getChronology b))
false
```

Although the hashcodes do

```
=> (= (.hashCode (.getChronology a)) (.hashCode (.getChronology b)))
true
```

But [joda.time.Chronology](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/Chronology.java) doesn't provide [its own equals method](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Chronology.html#methods.inherited.from.class.java.lang.Object) and inherits it from Object, which only uses reference equality.

My theory is that these dates are all being deserialized with their own individual, different, constructed Chronology objects, but JodaTime has [its own serializer](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/DateTime.java#L2101) which probably deals with this. Maybe a custom [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) serializer would help in this regard.

For now, **my solution to using JodaTime in Spark** is to use [org.joda.time .Instant](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Instant.html) by calling `toInstant`, or a `java.util.Date` rather than a [org.joda.time.DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html).

Both involve throwing away timezone information, which isn't ideal, so if anyone has more info it would be very welcome!

Comment: maybe you could use epoch time in millis representation instead of date/time objects. Looks like the safer alternative. We have had issues keying data with other hashes based on memory-location, like Java enums. They don't work on a distributed environment.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I (think I) suggested with Instant. Good to know I'm not the only one with this problem!

Comment: Are you using a heterogeneous mix of chronologies and time zones within an RDD?  If not, I would maintain that info at the RDD level and save on the memory footprint of each record (as you are doing with `Instant`)

Comment: No these are all in the same timezone, and this behaviour manifests for even the same original date object. I'm happy using instant (or even a tuple of numbers for that matter). It's just that this is strange.